# Machine Code Definition

Tags: c++, c, assembly

Is my definition of machine code right?

Machine code is the programming language which is native (understandable) only by a specific type of system or operating system and not by other system or operating system.

My teacher told it is wrong and the word native must not be used.

What is machine code?

Comment: Wikipedia has a whole page about [Machine Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)!

Comment: You are probably getting downvotes because you didn't search first or provide evidence thereof.

Comment: By the way, machine code really has nothing to do with the languages you tagged, especially Java.

Comment: Why didn't you list other languages that are compiled or generate intermediate forms?  For example FORTRAN is compiled into *machine code*.  The JVM does not convert into machine code, it actually executes the Java Byte Code, much like an interpreted language like BASIC.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you Thomas.

Comment: I suppose @ThomasMatthews was sarcastic. I deleted the fortran tag. Please do not add tags for all languages for which a compiler exist (there is no such thing as a compiled language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine code is the code written in the native instruction set of the machine. i.e. the CPU.  It is possible to write code which can run on different OSes, and different processors, though this is usually only done when there is relatively minor differences.

I used to have a program which could run on a Z80 or x86, on MS-DOS or CPM-86.